# MySQL Query with left outer join doesn't load

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to generate a big table from multiple table with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but it seems like the server times out before I get my result. Am I doing something wrong?

```
SELECT
    mtl_extended_info.TM,
    mtl_extended_info.EMP_ID,
    mtl_extended_info.DNAME,
    mtl_extended_info.STATUS,
    mtl_extended_info.SHIFT,
    mtl_extended_info.SKILL,
    IFNULL(cdl_metrics_all.Sched_Adh, '-') as Sched_Adh,
    IFNULL(cdl_metrics_all.Sched_Compl, '-') as Sched_Compl,
    IFNULL(SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Calls_Handled_Ct), '-') as Call_Handled,
    IFNULL(ROUND((SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.I_Talk_Time_Sec) + SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Hold_Time_Sec) + SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.I_Work_Time_Sec) + SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Calls_Handled_Ct)), '-') as AHT,
    IFNULL(cdl_metrics_all.AHT_Target, '-') as AHT_Target,
    IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.I_Talk_Time_Sec) / SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Calls_Handled_Ct)), '-') as TALK,
    IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.I_Work_Time_Sec) / SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Calls_Handled_Ct)), '-') as ACW,
    IFNULL(ROUND(SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Hold_Time_Sec) / SUM(enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Calls_Handled_Ct)), '-') as Hold,
    IFNULL(SUM(cdl_rr7_all.Score), '-') as R7,
    IFNULL(cdl_deact_all.Deact_Rate_Excl_Port, '-') AS DeactWOPort,
    IFNULL(cdl_deact_all.Deact_Rate_Incl_Port, '-') AS DeactPort,
    IFNULL(cdl_deact_all.Deac_Target, '-') as Deact_Target,
    IFNULL(TRUNCATE((SUM(cdl_cmp_oe_all.CMP_OE_Virtual) / SUM(cdl_cmp_oe_all.CMP_Surveys)), 2), '-') AS CMP_OE,
    IFNULL(SUM(cdl_cmp_oe_all.CMP_Surveys), '-') AS CMP_Surveys,
    IFNULL(cdl_metrics_all.ICV_WR, '-') as ICV_WR,
    IFNULL(cdl_metrics_all.ICV_WR_Target, '-') as ICV_WR_Target,
    IFNULL(cdl_metrics_all.ICV_CA, '-') as ICV_CA,
    IFNULL(cdl_metrics_all.ICV_CA_Target, '-') as ICV_CA_Target
FROM mtl_extended_info
    LEFT OUTER JOIN enterprise_rep_agent_stats ON enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Employee_ID = mtl_extended_info.EMP_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdl_metrics_all ON cdl_metrics_all.EMP_ID = mtl_extended_info.EMP_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdl_rr7_all ON cdl_rr7_all.EMP_ID = mtl_extended_info.EMP_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdl_deact_all ON cdl_deact_all.EMP_ID = mtl_extended_info.EMP_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdl_cmp_oe_all ON cdl_cmp_oe_all.EMP_ID = mtl_extended_info.EMP_ID
WHERE VISIBLE = 1
GROUP BY mtl_extended_info.EMP_ID, enterprise_rep_agent_stats.Month_Date
ORDER BY SM, TM
```

Expected result (This is just one line out of the 300 I am expecting):

```
TM          |   EMP_ID  |   DNAME       |   STATUS  |   mtl_extended_info.SHIFT |   mtl_extended_info.SKILL |   Sched_Adh   |   Sched_Compl |   Call_Handled    |   AHT |   AHT_Target  |   TALK    |   ACW |   Hold    |   R7  |   DeactWOPort |   DeactPort   |   Deact_Target    |   CMP_OE  |   CMP_Surveys |   ICV_WR  |   ICV_WR_Target   |   ICV_CA  |   ICV_CA_Target
Peter Pan   |   841255  |   John Doe    |   Active  |   Full Time               |   Cable Repair            |   90%         |   95%         |   641             |   954 |   800         |   641     |   83  |   56      |   86% |   73%         |   74%         |   Deact_Target    |   100%    |   14          |   86      |   1.4             |   -14.87  |   -12.4
```

I get the follow error: Error Code: 1317. Query execution was interrupted

Comment: heh, I think I recognize what company you work for by the column/table names.   Is this a shared server by any chance?  It's possible someone else is killing your long running query.

Comment: Yes, it's a shared server

Comment: I'd think I'd start there...if you are with the company I think you are with, you'll have 20 people all fighting for a pretty under powered server, long running queries locking other people up get killed without much consideration.  Do you notice it's a different length of time that it manages to run for each time?

Comment: You're executing a group by, but with non-aggregated columns. Although MySQL lets you do this, the results aren't predictable. First split into two queries, one that does the grouping and one that doesn't and then join the results.

Comment: do tests at localhost. I bet it's fine. 

only thing, i can recomend it's creating indexes for faster execution.

Comment: If you want help, you'll need to put table prefixes on all the columns, it's not clear what comes from where.

Comment: @Twelfth It's pretty consistent the result I get. But I am only getting 53 lines out of 300 I was expecting from my last working query

Comment: You're grouping by Month_Date, but not selecting it, what does that even mean? Are you expecting one row per employee per month? If so how do you know which month is which?

Comment: Listen to Laurence when it comes to how many lines you are returning, your group by is a bit fishy here.  If it isn't a calculated column, odds are you should have it in the group by statement.  1317 is very possible an execution time timeout as well...any chance you can move this entire thing to your local?

Comment: Table aliases exist for a reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, try something like this. There are bound to be syntax errors. Every table can benefit from an index on `emp_id` (or `month_date, employee_id`)

```
Select
    ei.TM,
    ei.emp_id,
    ei.DNAME,
    ei.STATUS,
    ei.SHIFT,
    ei.SKILL,
    ifnull(cm.Sched_Adh, '-') as Sched_Adh,
    ifnull(cm.Sched_Compl, '-') as Sched_Compl,
    ifnull(es.Call_Handled_Ct, '-') as Call_Handled,
    ifnull(es.AHT, '-') as AHT,
    ifnull(cm.AHT_Target, '-') as AHT_Target,
    ifnull(es.TALK, '-') as TALK,
    ifnull(es.ACW, '-') as ACW,
    ifnull(es.Hold, '-') as Hold,
    ifnull(cr.R7, '-') as R7,
    ifnull(cd.Deact_Rate_Excl_Port, '-') AS DeactWOPort,
    ifnull(cd.Deact_Rate_Incl_Port, '-') AS DeactPort,
    ifnull(cd.Deac_Target, '-') as Deact_Target,
    ifnull(cc.CMP_OE, '-') AS CMP_OE,
    ifnull(cc.CMP_Surveys, '-') AS CMP_Surveys,
    ifnull(cm.ICV_WR, '-') as ICV_WR,
    ifnull(cm.ICV_WR_Target, '-') as ICV_WR_Target,
    ifnull(cm.ICV_CA, '-') as ICV_CA,
    ifnull(cm.ICV_CA_Target, '-') as ICV_CA_Target
From
    mtl_extended_info ei
    Left Outer Join cdl_metrics_all cm on cm.emp_id = ei.emp_id
    Left Outer Join cdl_deact_all cd on cd.emp_id = ei.emp_id
    Left Outer Join (
        Select
            es.Employee_ID,
            es.Month_Date
            sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct) as Call_Handled,
            round((sum(es.I_Talk_Time_Sec) + sum(es.Hold_Time_Sec) + sum(es.I_Work_Time_Sec) + sum(es.I_AUX_Out_Time_Sec)) / sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct)) as AHT,
            round(sum(es.I_Talk_Time_Sec) / sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct)) as TALK,
            round(sum(es.I_Work_Time_Sec) / sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct)) as ACW,
            round(sum(es.Hold_Time_Sec) / sum(es.Calls_Handled_Ct)) as Hold
        From
            enterprise_rep_agent_stats es 
        Where
            es.Month_Date = $dynamic_value$
        Group By
            es.Employee_ID
    ) es on es.Employee_ID = ei.emp_id
    Left Outer Join (
        Select
            cr.emp_id,
            sum(cr.Score) as R7
        From
            cdl_rr7_all cr
        Group By
            cr.emp_id
    ) cr on cr.emp_id = ei.emp_id
    Left Outer Join (
        Select
            cc.emp_id,
            truncate((sum(cc.CMP_OE_Virtual) / sum(cc.CMP_Surveys)), 2) as CMP_OE,
            sum(cc.CMP_Surveys) as CMP_Surveys
        From
            cdl_cmp_oe_all cc
        Group By
            cc.emp_id
    ) cc on cc.emp_id = ei.emp_id
Where
    ei.Visible = 1
Order By
    ei.SM,
    ei.TM
```

There are still issues. Your example data for R7 produces a percentage, but the way the calculation works that looks suspect. Your previous example would have multi counted several things, I've assumed this was wrong and split each group by into a separate subquery.

Comment: `Month_Date` will be dynamic based on user selection in PHP. I am only using September as a reference. Sorry SM and TM comes from `cdl_extended_info`

Comment: I've put a placeholder in for the dynamic value. An index on `(month_date, employee_id)` will probably be useful. Does one employee have more than one `enterprise_rep_agent_stats` record per month?

Comment: It's daily that's why I have to sum it up for the month. It worked! Thanks so much! There's a couple issues but I fixed it! Thank you so much!! :D